# Merging multiple (almost) duplicate each statements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following set of `each` statements that are almost identical. I need to add about 20 more that follow a similar pattern. I'm trying to figure out how to take the small variables and update them into a single statement (instead of the same, slightly different thing 20 times).

```
$.each(mainData.name.source_values, function(index, val) {
  $("#matrix_datatable").find('#mNames')
    .append($('<td class="tableCells">')
    .append(val.value + '</td>')
  )
}); 
$.each(mainData.description.source_values, function(index, val) {
  $("#matrix_datatable").find('#mDescription')
    .append($('<td class="tableCells">')
    .append(val.value + '</td>')
  )
});
$.each(mainData.subtitle.source_values, function(index, val) {
  $("#matrix_datatable").find('#mSubtitle')
    .append($('<td class="tableCells">')
    .append(val.value + '</td>')
  )
});
```

As you can see, the only thing different in each is `name,description,subtitle` and `mNames,mDescription,mSubtitle`. How can I combine this into a single statement that uses an array (or something) of these two sets of "variables" that contain all 20+ of those I need to dig through:

```
var $dataPoints = ['name','description','subtitle'];
var $tableIds = ['mNames','mDescription','mSubtitle'];
```

Comment: Smells like the start of an extracted method!

Comment: @Taplar I have no idea what that is or how to use it.

Comment: Method === a function.  Make a function that has the common parts of your logic, and pass in the variables that are different between them for it to use.

Comment: Any chance you can give me a little headstart?

Comment: is `source_values` a simple array? then use `source_values.forEach` instead

Comment: Most of the answers are over looking that appending 'someting </td>' to a dom element is not valid.  The appending of a '<td>' unclosed will auto close it as it is creating dom elements.  You are not appending to a string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can **extract a function** in order to [Don't Repeat Yourself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself):

```
function append(id) {
    return function(index, val) {
        $('#matrix_datatable').find(id)
             // if your value doesn't contain HTML, opt for this
            .append($('<td>', { class: 'tableCells', text: val.value })
            // if it contains html, replace `text` with `html`
        );
    };
}

$.each(mainData.name.source_values, append('#mName'));
$.each(mainData.description.source_values, append('#mDescription'));
$.each(mainData.subtitle.source_values, append('#mSubtitle'));
```

You can also loop over your `$.each`:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
     $.each(mainData[$dataPoints[i]].source_values, append('#'+$tableIds[i]))
}
```

In fact there are plenty of way to refactor this code!

Comment: I feel a little bit bad helping you on this: refactoring is the best way to learn by self IMO. But there are plenty of other times you'll need to refactor code, so keep DRY in mind and enjoy :)

Comment: This looks like the best approach, I would echo an earlier comment though about appending `</td>`'s in that way and instead reduce it the append line in the append function to something like: `.append($('<td/>',{ class: "tableCells", text: val.value });`

Answer (score 4):

First step, extract out your common logic to a function that you can reuse, instead of repeating it over and over

```
function addTableCells ( elements, targetId ) {
    $.each(elements, function(index, val) {
        $("#matrix_datatable").find(targetId)
            .append($('<td class="tableCells">'+ val.value +'</td>');
    });
}
```

Comment: To be on the safe side: `append($('<td class="tableCells">', {text: val.value}))`

Comment: Maybe the value contains html he wants.  Idk his entire use case.

Comment: then change text for html

Comment: How would that be different from this?  If his value does have html and it is malformed, then that's something else he has to fix.

Comment: you never know what value can contain

Comment: You should.  It's your application.  If you don't know, that's very poor application management, input/out sanitation, which is again another issue that would need to be addressed.

Answer (score 1):

The goal it seems from your question is to extract a function that can be executed multiple times and produce similar results. By defining a function that performs the same iteration, find and append operation on parameterized variables you can use this function multiple times.

Something like this should be what you're looking for:

```
function updateDom(arrayOfValues, parentElementId, childElementId) {
    $.each(arrayOfValues, function(index, val) {
       $('#' + parentElementId).find('#' + childElementId)
       .append($('<td class="tableCells">')
       .append(val.value + '</td>'))});
}
```

Comment: You can do something like this

Comment: How and where do I store `arrayOfValues` and `childElementId` so this function can access? Are these the names of the arrays?

Comment: @jonmrich as a global variable or a local variable obtained from some other routine

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this.

```
var lst = [mainData.name.source_values, mainData.description.source_values, mainData.subtitle.source_values];
var ids = ["mNames", "mDescription", "mSubtitle"];

for (i = 0; i < lst.length; i++) {
    $.each(lst[i], function(index, val) {
        $("#matrix_datatable").find( "#" + ids[i] )
            .append($("<td class='tableCells'>")
            .append(val.value + "</td>")
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if this is what you intend to do, but what about wrapping your 
each inside a foreach :)

```
var dataPoints = ['name','description','subtitle'];
dataPoints.forEach( (field) => {
   var tableId = <generate table id from field string, add letter m and camelcase the field name>;
   $.each(mainData[field].source_values, function(index, val) {
     $("#matrix_datatable").find('#' + tableId)
      .append($('<td class="tableCells">')
      .append(val.value + '</td>')
     )
   }); 
});
```